# Convert a jquery object containing form elements like input and select into json

Tags: jquery, json

I have got the following HTMLTableRowElement. I need to convert it into json based on the name fields and corresponding values of the input and select elements. Is there a library or jquery method to do it?  Jquery's serializeArray method is returning an empty array when called on the jquery object of the row, like this $('the following HTMLTableRowElement').serializeArray().

```
<tr id="row7">
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="person_row7" name="person_row7">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="father_row7" name="father_row7">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="input-mini" type="text" id="age_row7" name="age_row7">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="gender_row7" class="input-small" name="gender_row7">
                <option value="" selected="selected">
                    ---------
                </option>
                <option>
                    Male
                </option>
                <option>
                    Female
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="phonenumber_row7" name="phonenumber_row7" type="text">
        </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the form elements inside the tr - serializeArray won't work on a tr - only form element and form controls

From jQuery [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) docs

> This method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`. However, it is typically easier to select the `<form>` tag itself for serialization:

```
// serialize all form controls with a name attribute
$('#row7 :input[name]').serializeArray();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UdQKK/)